# Is there a way to proxy an SPA Blazor app througha Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this Blazor app previously initialized and served that I want to host inside a WebAPI project and make it go out through a path segment (`/ui/*`). I have this idea:

```cs
app.Map("/ui/*", opts =>
{
  opts.UseSpa(spa => {
    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:44326");
    //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                                 Blazor app host to be proxified
  });
});
```

I'm getting a `401` since I need to authorize that path and a `404` if I remove authorization.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It seems that you wanna a url rewrite feature. So what's your plan on publishing your app?

Comment: Same behavior... since we can afford another VM for host and run the pipeline... But I think is more a proxy (maybe reverse) behavior...